# writing multiple arrays in one remains empty when only one array to add

Tags: php, arrays, xml, html

I load a xml-file which contains several arrays.

```
$array0 = (.......)
$array1 = (.......)
...
$arrayN = (.......)
```

In my HTML-part I have a DIV to display each array. To do it write all arrays in one masterarray:

```
for ( $i = 0; $i < 1; $i++) $masterArray[] = ${'array'.$i};
```

and can access each array

```
$Titel = $masterArray[0] [$i] [$kat] [0] ["TitelD"];
```

This works if I have more than one array in my xml-File. If I have only one the masterarray rests empty. Why that? If I copy a second in the xml-File it works... (with displaying the second!)

What can I do to get only one array in the masterarray?

This XML works:

[image]

and when changing the url to this xml-file (in the same html/php-file) the DIV is empty:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

change this

```
for ( $i = 0; $i < 1; $i++)
```

to

```
for ( $i = 0; $i <= 1; $i++)
```

Comment: Thanks, but still no success.